# After the Japanese declaration of War, what happened to the Japanese Embassy in Washington DC?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two, japan, diplomacy

The [Japanese Declaration of War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_declaration_of_war_on_the_United_States_and_the_British_Empire) against the UK and USA was given on 1941 Dec 7. This happened in Washington DC via the Japanese Embassy.

I would like to know what happened to that embassy and the Japanese diplomats there. Were they arrested and sent to an [internment camp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internment_of_Japanese_Americans)? Was the embassy raided for documents and shut down?

I did see this article of [Nomura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kichisabur%C5%8D_Nomura), which says

> On August 20, 1942, Nomura returned to Japan. He continued to serve in an unofficial capacity as an advisor to the government through World War II, and was appointed to the Privy Council in May 1945.

However, it is unsourced and does not give details, e.g., was he arrested and spent half a year in an internment camp before being released to Japan? And I'm asking about all the Japanese diplomats at the embassy, not just Nomura.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for suspecting Japanese embassy personnel might have been "arrested and sent to an interment camp"? As a rule, this does not happen to diplomats.

Comment: @Semaphore This is not a duplicate. That question is asking about what happened to diplomats in general. I'm asking about what actually happened to these specific Japanese diplomats in particular. If you think general vs specifics are necessarily the same things, you are gravely mistaken. The question "what happened to US soldiers in general?" has the answer "most of them survived the war." The question "what happened to Joseph P Kennedy Jr." has a completely different answer. If you don't want to answer it, please kindly re-open it so that others will have a chance.

Comment: @Semaphore And yes ofc i have a specific reason. I linked to the Japanese Internment Camps (btw, there were Canadian ones too). That alone seems enough of a suspicion. For another thing, why wait 7 months before returning Nomura? Again, please re-open the question. If you don't want to answer it, please do not stop others from having a chance.

Comment: In fact, **that question specifically asked how Japanese diplomats were treated after the DoW** in WW2. In this case the repeated suggestion that they could have been sent to internment camps (they were not) led me to think your question is also about their treatment by the US. *If instead it's about why it took them 8 months to get back to Japan, or how they traveled, I certainly would agree it's a separate and worthy question.* If that is your focus, please do edit to make it clear. Either way, there's no need for the hostility; questions are put on hold only so that they can be clarified.

Comment: Also, in the case of duplicated questions, everyone does indeed have a chance to answer the question in the previous post - that's how duplicate works. I do readily concede the other question could use answers with more specific details about what happened to the diplomats before they were repatriated, or perhaps a new but narrowly focused question on where they waited for repatriation.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabur%C5%8D_Kurusu , the diplomats were interned  in Hot Springs (at I think a luxry hotel, but don't have references handy) and then (in mid 1942) were sent by neutral ship to a neutral country.

Comment: I have supplied an answer to THIS question by adding an answer to THAT supposed duplicate.